# How do I perform function on tuples within a list comprehension? Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I have a type called image which holds a set of tuples, which are coordinates. I am trying to make a list comprehension where I can print out max and min of the list of either the x or y coordinates.

```
example :: Image -> (Int,Int)
example e = [ (j,k) | (x,y) <- e, j <- (maximum x), k <- (minimum y)]
```

I want to print (max x, min x) as a starter.

I keep getting an error, could someone please show me the correct way of doing this.

edit: Thanks to the answer, I have changed the second line to:

```
example e = [ (j,k) | (x,y) <- e, let j = maximum x, let k = minimum y]
```

however get this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘Int’
Relevant bindings include j :: a (bound at image.hs:69:39)
In the first argument of ‘maximum’, namely ‘x’
In the expression: maximum x
```

for both j and k

Comment: Can you show some sample code, so that we can help you out better ?

Comment: So you have something like `[(Int, Int)]` and you want something like `([Int], [Int])`?  Use `unzip`.

Comment: Showing the error itself would also be extremely helpful.  Haskell's strict typing lends itself to be very informative about why a given statement is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer:

Here are the definitions of `Image` and `Point`:

```
type Image = [Point]
type Point = (Int,Int)
```

And how `example` should be written:

```
example :: Image -> (Int,Int)
example e = (maximum xs, minimum xs)
  where xs = map fst e   -- xs = list of the x coordinates
        ys = map snd e   -- ys = list of the y coordinates
```

Original answer:

Use `let`:

```
example e = [ (j,k) | (x,y) <- e, let j = maximum x, let k = minimum y]
```

Comment: that gives me this error:                                      image.hs:69:51:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘Int’
    Relevant bindings include j :: a (bound at image.hs:69:39)
    In the first argument of ‘maximum’, namely ‘x’
    In the expression: maximum x

Comment: What is the definition of `Image`?

Comment: a list of type Point, which is defined (Int,Int). So its [Point]

Comment: thanks, working now. what if I wanted to get max and min for snd also, how would I do that? using where twice gave me an error

Comment: You don't use `where` twice. Answer updated - see how `ys` is defined.